# custom rows in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

i have the following problem, I am writing an app that repeats the http://www.rottentomatoes.com/mobile/ website, if you look on the site there are deviders the "Opening this Week", "Top Box Office" and "Also in Theaters" so my question is, how do i add this custom rows to the ListView that holds all the movies

here is what i have so far, please pitch me some ideas so it will look exactly like on the site
[image]

Comment: no, i tried nothing, i have no idea how it should be done, i am very new to android, and nothing suitable i found on google.

Comment: Sorry disregard my original comment. ExpandableListView is not a good idea. I would go with @matiash first option, by including the dividers in your custom layout and play with VISIBLE and GONE.

Comment: @Lazy Ninja can you or give me a sample code so i know how to go about it? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to include the dividers in the layout of item views. Then make them `VISIBLE` only when the view maps to the first item of a new category, otherwise leave them as `GONE`.

Example (in semi-pseudocode):

First, make your item layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>
    <TextView id=divider>
    <your original item layout>
</LinearLayhout>
```

Then, in the adapter's `getView()`:

```
Film item = getItem(position);
boolean needsDivider = (position == 0 || getItem(position - 1).filmCategory != film.filmCategory);
if (needsDivider)
{
    dividerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dividerView.setText(getFilmCategoryName(film.filmCategory));
}
else
    dividerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

A more fancy solution would be to use a library like [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders). It doesn't work as your mobile site example, but it's probably even better (e.g. the headers don't scroll up out of the screen).

Comment: can you give me the sample code to the first option?